# What does `Ot` means in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, google-chrome-devtools

I'm playing with d3 and when I log a selection, this is the result:

[image]

what is `Ot`?

Comment: "Ot" lost its meaning because you're observing structure produced by minified version of JS code. Usually it should represent class name of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grey text before an object indicates the original Class name, consider the following example:

```js
class TestClass {
    constructor() {
        this.a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
        this.b = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
    }
}

const res = {}
res.test = new TestClass();
console.log(res);
```

Here, we're logging `res` which contains a `Test` class on the `.test` property, then the `console.log` looks like this:

[image]